# Autocomplete jquery search results to the defined pages

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I'm trying to get a static , pre-defined search results while using a autocomplete jquery.

Let me explain it more specific.

I'm editing : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple and just tried multiple form actions but never get a good result.

```
var availableTags = [
      "Apple",
      "Red",
      "iPhone"];
```

So the thing is seems really easy but as far as I'm noob its hard to figure it out.

When I type "apple" in the input are and click Go button (via form action or anything) i want to go to "sitename.com/apple" address.

When I type both "apple,iPhone" and click , i want to go to "sitename.com/apple+iphone" address.

When I type both "red,iphone" and click i want to go to "sitename.com/red+iphone" address.

I had make several trials but input value makes me crazy like ; sitename.com/q?=apple , and I couldnt find a way to just show /apple without "x?=" .

I'm happy to define all patways manually and i'm seeking help for this stiuation.

Thanks !

I tried like  :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Apple",
      "Red",
      "iphone"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( "," );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="get" action="http://example.com">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="tags" name="asd" size="50">
</div>
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

1. Join the terms with a `+` in your select function

`this.urlValue = terms.join("+");`

2. Handle the form submit to redirect to the correct URL

For example:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove the last + from url value
    var urlValue = $('#tags')[0].urlValue.slice(0, -1);

    // Redirect to the url
    window.location.href = 'http://sitename.com/' + urlValue;
});
```

Hope this helps. Below is a demo to illustrate.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/nwd3ofse/)</kbd>